# How can I undo/redo in iOS Notes.app w/o shaking my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app, undo-redo

Are there alternative ways to quickly undo/redo changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2019 Update

iOS 13 now supports gestures to easily undo/redo!

- Three finger swipe:

  - right to left - *undo*
  - left to right - *redo*
- Double-tap with three fingers - *undo*
- Three finger tap - open shortcut menu containing buttons to *undo*, *cut*, *copy*, *paste*, and *redo* (screenshot below)

[image: three finger tap shows menu]

More info about the new gestures (including *copy*, *cut*, and *paste*) can be found in this [article](https://9to5mac.com/2019/06/12/gestures-undo-ios-iphone-ipad/).

*NOTE*: These gestures should work across all apps that support undo/redo functionality!

Hat tip to [@Jaime Santa Cruz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/38539/jaime-santa-cruz)'s [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370700/151404), which prompted this update.

---

You can now press undo/redo buttons in iOS 11 on the iPhone!

Open notes, view a note in landscape, and you'll see arrows on the bottom left!

[image]

*NOTE: Seems to only work with notes under an iCloud account*

Answer (score 3):

There’s a new gesture under iOS 13 which allows you to tap with three fingers to bring an edit menu. Double tapping with three fingers is a global undo.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly clumsy solution, but you can use **AssistiveTouch**.

It's  in Settings > General > Accessibility. It gives you a menu that includes things like Gestures (2+ finger gestures with only one finger), Lock Screen, Mute/Unmute ... and Shake.

I find that the popup menu button gets in the way (although you can drag it around), so I assigned turning it on/off to a triple-click-home-button action (Accessibility Shortcut).

If you have iOS 11,  you can also quickly enable/disable it from Control Center if you add the Accessibility widget.

[image: AssistiveTouch-downsized]

<sub>*[downsized for browsers that don't resize high-DPI images]*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

To undo:

1. Tap the pen icon.
2. Tap the undo icon.

Here is the demo video:

https://youtu.be/Cq7A6OSTUpA

Comment: Cool, didn’t realize you could do that via markup. Is there a benefit to this method over the previously stated solutions?

Comment: @JBallin : Other methods don't work for me, this is the only solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad: Get rid of the keyboard. There will be
the undo icon behind it.